# Metric for binary segmentation network

Tags: keras, deep-learning, metrics, image-segmentation

I am working on segmentation with 2 classes (object and background), and I have 2 types of unbalance:
1. inside the image - the object of interest is small with respect to the background
2. about 80% of my images are only background.

I want to know which metrics are good for this situation.

I think that using F1 on each image and then averaging (like keras does) is wrong because the images without any objects will change the results drastically (for example, if I have only one pixel which is FP on empty image, I get F-score of zero while its very good segmentation).

What is the right way to test the performance of my network?

thank you all